# no supported authentication methods available (server sent publickey) Putty Windows

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, putty

Good evening everyone ,
I created an instance on my OvhCloud host,
I followed the whole process from key generation to configuration of the instance detailed on this link: https://docs.ovh.com/fr/public-cloud/premiers-pas-instance-public-cloud/
Now I use Putty to connect to this instance created with the private key generated on PuttyGen.
But I can't access my instance I get this error (**no supported authentication methods available (server sent publickey)**

I would like to know where the problem lies ???

Comment: What version of PuTTY are you using?  What OS are you using on the remote side?

Comment: PuTTY 0.78 and remote server OS is ubuntu 22